# How to start session with php code

Tags: php, session, curl, session-cookies

I would like to send request to [server](http://www.rvvi.cz). I am using this code for it

```
$data=[..];

$header=[
"Accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Connection: keep-alive",
"Host: www.rvvi.cz",
"Referer: https://www.rvvi.cz/riv?s=rozsirene-vyhledavani",
"Upgrade-Insecure_Requests:1",
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/2010",
"Cookie: PHPSESSID=4ck9tc3vm4prgfubnjvutilgd2",
"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 ];

$url = "https://www.rvvi.cz/riv";
$query = http_build_query($data);
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,strlen($query));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$query);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$page=curl_exec($ch);
echo($page);
```

but problem is with PHPSESSID in header. To access that, i have to manually go to this server with my browser ( this that probably start my SESSION ), copy PHPSESSID and paste it into my script. But, i would like to make this script automatic. I need to to active them from my server without using browser or copying something. 
Is there any way how can i start this session just with my php code?

Comment: Sessions expire, so this will break. You’ll need to find another way to authenticate.

Comment: And do you know some way how to do it please? One of my attempts was made request with file_get_contents first, and get this PHPSESSID from $http_response_header. But it doesn´t work.

Comment: It depends. Ideally the site should offer some kind of API that you can authenticate with and then make your request. Otherwise, you could try and login using another cURL request and then use the cookie that was set, but that’s really messy and a pain in the backside. API is the best route. Your question is pretty broad so not completely suitable for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
$curl = curl_init( 'https://httpbin.org/post' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'field1' => 'some data', 'field2' => 'some more data' ) );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
```